# onSubmit redirect to website depenfing on value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, authentication, passwords

Hi I'm trying to create a simple login form with 2 or 3 users where depending on who is logging in the redirect should be to different urls.

My code so far:

HTML

```
  <h1 class="title">Logga in</h1>

<div class="grid__container">

  <form name="login" onSubmit="return validateForm();" action="some website url" method="post" class="form form--login">

    <div class="form__field">
      <label class="fontawesome-user" for="login__username"><span class="hidden">Username</span></label>
      <input name="usernameInput" id="login__username" type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Username" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form__field">
      <label class="fontawesome-lock" for="login__password"><span class="hidden">Password</span></label>
      <input name="passwordInput" id="login__password" type="password" class="form__input" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form__field">
      <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

JavaScript

```
        function validateForm() {
            var username = document.login.usernameInput.value;
            var password = document.login.passwordInput.value;
            var username1 = "user 1";
            var password1 = "1234";
            var username2 = "user 2";
            var password2 = "4321";
            if ((username == username1) && (password == password1)){
                return "www.google.se";
            }else if (username == username2) && (password == password2) {
                return "www.facebook.se";
            }else{
                alert ("Login was unsuccessful, please check your username and password");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I got the feeling such redirection should happen on server side.

Comment: I'm just playing around so not writing any server side code.  I was hoping this could be done with javascript

Comment: window.location.href="http://google.se";
return false;

Comment: @JohanEnstam What you are trying to do doesn't make too much sense to me. Do you want to submit the form to different url, or do you want to redirect your page after you got your post form response? Or you don't really care about submitting a form and just want to go to different url based on user name?

Comment: Sorry if I'm unclear. What I want to achieve is when the user inputs the correct username and password to redirect to a new site. Also for this to be possible with more than just one username/password. Should I use a switch statement or something similar?